# What happens if I don't ejaculate for a number of weeks / months?

Tags: penis, masturbation, ejaculation, vagina, oral-sex

What would happen if I don't have sex or masturbate my penis?

Will my semen ejaculate on its own because of the overload in production?  Maybe a wet dream at night?

Or will I just not ejaculate at all?

Is there like a maximum number of months that I can go without ejaculating?

If I don't ejaculate for like a year, will it cause me any health issues?